# Weights given by MLPClassifier in sklearn.neural_network (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I am currently working on the MLPClassifier of the neural_network package in sklearn.

I have fit the model; I want to access the weights given by the classifier to the input features. How do I access them?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use print model.coefs_

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check out the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html).
See the field coefs_.

Try:

```
print model.coefs_
```

Generally, I recommend:

- checking the documentation
- if that fails, then

  ```
  print dir(model)
  ```

  or

  ```
  help(model)
  ```

  will tell you what's available for in most cases.

Comment: Hi, Can a share an example where I can give more weight to the data labelled as 1 rather than that with 0 and 2? I have a highly imbalanced dataset which MLP Classifier is performing very poorly. Thanks in advance